# How do you obtain the anchor part of a URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to obtain anchor part of URL after `#` in JavaScript? This is related with [How to obtain anchor part of URL after # in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032242/php-question)

Comment: @santanu, please edit the title of your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 10):

To get the "anchor part" of the current page, you can use:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Then, based on your question link, you want to send it to a PHP script.  You can do this with a JavaScript redirect like so:

```
window.location = "myscript.php?hash=" + encodeURIComponent(hash);
```

However, this won't work for users without JavaScript enabled, so be sure to have a `<noscript>` message ready!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var url = "http://nhs/search-panel.php#?patientid=2";
var hash = url.match(/^[^#]*#(.*)/)[1];
```

See also [doing substring in window.location.hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824040/doing-substring-in-window-location-hash)